# Stopping a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

I've got a home task writing a programme in which the user inputs his name and surname and the output should be the initials.
The problem is that applying this programme I get a line of initials which are repeated 10 times.

How can I get the output of just one pair of initials?

I've already searched the web and this website as well and tried to apply such things as return and break but it didn't help me.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    // get string of the text
    string s = GetString();

    // output the initials of the name
    if (s != NULL)
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)  // was for (…; i = 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[i]); j < n; j++)  // was for (…; j = 0)
            {
                printf ("%c%c", argv[1][0], argv[2][0]);
            }
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Just a though: Throw an exception..

Comment: But first format the code :)

Comment: Note that you should not modify the question so as to invalidate answers.  You ask the user for some input, and then completely ignore it.  You exit from `main()` with `return 0;` after completing the inner loop for the first time, which is unlikely to be what you wanted.  You do avoid calling `strlen()` repeatedly on the same string; that's good. You _do_ need to revisit this code to clean up your logic — though you if you post the revised code to SO it should be as an addition to what's here rather than replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is infinite loop as i and j are being reassigned to 0. 
"for loop" structure should be like: 
for ( init; condition; increment )
please use below "for loop" in your program.

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[i]); j < n; j++)
```

---

To get initials of Name. Take input (name) as String and find length of string (length_of_input) and use below code:

```
for(int i=0; i< (length_of_input-1); i++){
 //First letter is always initial
   if(i==0){
       // print character at i position
        printf ("%c",name[i]);
    }
   //if there is space, then next character is initial
   if(name[i] == ' '){
         printf ("%c",name[i+1]);  //print next character
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, the outer loop too!

Comment: I've tried to do it in the very beginning, but in this case I don't get the desired output. The output should be the initials of the name entered. For example, if I enter Peter Williams the output should be PW

Answer (score 1):

your inner loop never finishes, because its stop condition will never be reached.

```
for (int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[i]); j < n; j = 0)
```

You most likely meant

```
for(int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[i]); j < n; j++)
```

As pointed out by Varsha, you have the same problem with the outer loop too. Seems that you need to freshen up your knowledge of C loops :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I changed some points in the code, but still I get the line where initials are repeated for about 10 times.

Comment: @IrynaRozhko: well, time for some actual debugging then. It seems that you __don't__ need any loops there.